# RACSignal from NSSegmentedControl's selectedSegment property

Tags: objective-c, macos, reactive-cocoa, nssegmentedcontrol

A NSSegmentedControl instance is bound to a ViewController as

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSSegmentedControl *mySegmentedControl;
```

In the viewDidLoad method, a signal is created (and subscribed to) for the selectedSegment property of the NSSegmentedControl:

```
[RACObserve(self.mySegmentedControl, selectedSegment) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"Next is called only once.");
}];
```

The subscribeNext block is however only executed once, just after the creation of the signal, no error nor complete messages are sent.

When using the `hidden` instead of the `selectedSegment` property for example, the subscribeNext block gets executed whenever the `hidden` state of the NSSegmentedControl changes.

Is this a KVO issue? How do I solve this, i.e. how to make a RACSignal from the selectedSegment property of a NSSegmentedControl?

(This is a Mac issue only, iOS has some nifty categories on UIControl and its subclasses that seem to do the trick).

Comment: Have you seen this discussion on RAC github repo? https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1849

Comment: I did and it was of no help to me. It is not a main thread issue and the discussion talks about `rac_signalForControlEvents` which is defined on UIControl, not NSControl.